# What benefit does the opening and closing of "wings" have for Star Wars fighters?

Tags: star-wars

The X-Wing opens its wings when in combat mode, but what purpose do the two modes have? Usually a fighter will become sleeker for higher speed, and then open itself up to allow better manoeuvring; but in space there is no benefit in terms of aerodynamics.

So what are the benefits in Star Wars to opening up wings?

Comment: The wings open so the laser cannons can be better cooled, and thus increase the rate of fire greatly.  This is from video games like Jedi Starfighter and may not be Disney Approved Canon.